# Optimal ordering of items with contradictory constraints

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I've got a collection of testcases and I want to find the optimal order in which to run them. The order constraints are either:

- Hard: one testcase `A` can produce output that is required for another testcase `B`, so `A` *must* be processed before `B`
- Soft: testcases can inherit input data from another. If the parent testcase fails, it's almost certain that the child testcase will fail in the same way. In order to make failure diagnosis easier we'd like to run the parent first, so when we come to run the child we can look up past results and skip the child if the parent failed. i.e.: if testcase `B` inherits from `A`, it'd be *nice* (but by no means essential) if `A` is processed before `B`

If we had *either* of these constraint sets we could just do a [topographical sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) and be done with it, but combining the two seems to make things trickier as they can contradict each other.

I can see two possible solutions:

#### Dual ranking

Give each item 2 ranks: the depths of the item in the hard and soft constraint trees. We can then sort based on these ranks - sort priority given to the hard constraint rank, and the soft constraint rank being compared when the hard constraint rank is equal.

This would certainly give us a valid order, but we might end up with a lot of unnecessarily-broken soft constraints. For example, consider items `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`, where:

- `A` *must* come before `B`
- `C` *must* come before `D`
- It'd be *nice* if `B` came before `C`

The hard-constraint ranking (`A:1,B:2,C:1,D:2`) implies a hard constraint between  `C` and `B` that does not actually exist, and we end up with order `A,C,B,D` when we'd prefer `A,B,C,D`

#### Constraint traversal

Build up the order list `L` from the set of item `S`:

1. Remove an arbitrary item `A` from `S`
2. recursively add all of `A`'s hard-constraint predecessors that are not already in `L` and remove them from `S`
3. recursively add all of `A`'s soft-constraint predecessors that are still in `S`, removing them from `S`
4. Add `A` to `L`
5. Repeat till `S` is empty.

I *think* this produces a valid order that only breaks soft constraints when necessary (it certainly works for the example above), but I'm not convinced we can't do better.

#### The question

Is there an accepted approach to the problem of finding an item ordering that fully satisfies one set of constraints while maximizing the satisfaction of another?

Comment: Which kind of constraint wins, when there's a contradiction. I'm guessing hard. If so, here's an idea: do a topological sort using just the hard constraints. Then, one by one (in some order), try and apply the soft constraints. If doing so, for a particular constraint, induces a cycle, then that soft constraint gets thrown away. Carry on until you've considered every soft constraint.

Comment: Yeah: the hard constraints must be satisfied, but it's not the end of the world if we break a soft one.
Your suggestion seems OK for simple examples when the items to swap are next to each other, but I don't have a sense of how it would work for more complex cases. For example: we find that A and B need to be swapped to satisfy a soft constraint, but they are 100 places distant in the current ordering. How do we choose their new positions in the ordering while still satisfying all of the hard constraints that might exist within those 100 positions?

Comment: Got any test data?

Comment: None that I can really publish I'm afraid. At any rate I strongly suspect that I'm wildly overthinking the actual problem in front of me - I could _probably_ do the dual-ranking thing described above without getting bad results. It'd just annoy me to sub-optimal :-/

Comment: I think it'd be a better fit for [CS](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @yeputons good call, [posted](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/93340/optimal-ordering-of-items-with-contradictory-constraints)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this question over on the [CS stackoverflow](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/93340/optimal-ordering-of-items-with-contradictory-constraints) revealed that what we're trying to find here is the *maximum acyclic subgraph*. This is an NP-hard problem, so there isn't really a quick, optimal solution.

I've implemented this graph class that gives a reasonable solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class DirectedWeightedGraph<T> {

    private final Map<T, Node<T>> nodes = new HashMap<>();

    public DirectedWeightedGraph( Collection<T> values ) {
        values.forEach( v -> nodes.put( v, new Node<>( v ) ) );
    }

    /**
     * Adds edges to the graph
     * 
     * @param weight The weight of the edges
     * @param target A function from edge origin to target. Returns <code>null</code> for no edge.
     * @return <code>this</code>
     */
    public DirectedWeightedGraph<T> edge( int weight, UnaryOperator<T> target ) {
        nodes.forEach( ( o, n ) -> Optional.ofNullable( target.apply( o ) )
            .ifPresent( t -> n.edgeTo( nodes.get( t ), weight ) ) );
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Removes cycles from the graph by removing the lowest-weight edge in each cycle
     * 
     * @return <code>this</code>
     */
    public DirectedWeightedGraph<T> removeCycles() {
        nodes.values().forEach( n -> n.removeCycles() );
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return The graph node values, in an order such that linked-<i>to</i> values come before
     *         linked-<i>from</i> values. Note that cycles in the graph will result in incorrect
     *         results
     * @see #removeCycles()
     */
    public List<T> order() {
        List<T> order = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<T> values = new HashSet<>( nodes.keySet() );
        while ( !values.isEmpty() ) {
            T t = values.iterator().next();
            nodes.get( t ).add( order, values );
        }
        return order;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nodes.values().stream()
            .map( n -> n.toString() )
            .sorted()
            .collect( Collectors.joining( "\n" ) );
    }

    private static class Node<T> {

        private enum State {
            /**
             * Node has not been visited yet
             */
            UNKNOWN,
            /**
             * Node is being explored
             */
            EXPLORING,
            /**
             * Node and all descendants are not part of a cycle
             */
            ACYCLIC
        }

        public final T value;
        private final Set<Edge<T>> edges = new HashSet<>();
        private State state = State.UNKNOWN;
        private Edge<T> lastExplored;

        public Node( T value ) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public Node<T> edgeTo( Node<T> target, int weight ) {
            edges.add( new Edge<>( this, target, weight ) );
            return this;
        }

        public Node<T> remove( Edge<T> e ) {
            edges.remove( e );
            return this;
        }

        public void removeCycles() {
            if ( state == State.ACYCLIC ) {
                return;
            }
            else if ( state == State.UNKNOWN ) {
                // recurse!
                state = State.EXPLORING;
                Set<Edge<T>> iterate = new HashSet<>( edges );
                for ( Edge<T> e : iterate ) {
                    if ( edges.contains( e ) ) {
                        lastExplored = e;
                        e.to.removeCycles();
                    }
                }
                lastExplored = null;
                state = State.ACYCLIC;
            }
            else if ( state == State.EXPLORING ) {
                // we've been here before!

                // Trace through the lastExplored edges till we're back here again to find the minimum
                // weight edge
                Edge<T> minimum = lastExplored;
                Node<T> n = lastExplored.to;
                while ( n != this ) {
                    if ( minimum.weight > n.lastExplored.weight ) {
                        minimum = n.lastExplored;
                    }
                    n = n.lastExplored.to;
                }

                // delete the lightest edge in the cycle. Choosing the optimal edge to delete is the bit
                // that makes this problem NP-hard, so let's not bother worrying about it too much
                minimum.delete();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Adds the node's prerequisites (the nodes that it links to), then itself to the list
         * 
         * @param order The list to build
         * @param values The set of nodes not yet in the last
         */
        public void add( List<T> order, Set<T> values ) {
            if ( values.remove( value ) ) {
                edges.forEach( e -> e.to.add( order, values ) );
                order.add( value );
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return value + edges.stream().map( e -> "\n\t" + e ).collect( Collectors.joining() );
        }
    }

    private static class Edge<T> {

        public final Node<T> from;
        public final Node<T> to;
        public final int weight;

        public Edge( Node<T> from, Node<T> to, int weight ) {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
            this.weight = weight;
        }

        public void delete() {
            from.remove( this );
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return from.value + "-" + weight + "->" + to.value;
        }
    }
}
```

The hard constraint edges are given a higher weight than those for the soft constraints, so we'll always delete a soft constraint when breaking cycles in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Topological sort based on your hard constraints with a program such as this: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Topological_sort#Python, which outputs items that can be applied in any order.

Apply any soft constraints that only order between items that had the same priority after the hard constraint ordering to split into suborders.

Comment: This sounds like what I was trying to describe in the "Dual Ranking" section of the question, have I misunderstood?